# Pie Chart Labels Overlapping using MPAndroidChart Library

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using PhilJay [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library:

`implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'`

And I implemented Pie Chart. Pie Chart with much entries cause labels overlapping as below:
[image]

But I need something like the below chart. This is very very beautiful without any overlap and with label background:

[image]

This is my code:

```
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, getString(R.string.chart_guide));
dataSet.setDrawValues(DRAW_VALUES); // To show/not show Slice Texts
dataSet.setDrawIcons(DRAW_ICONS);
dataSet.setSliceSpace(0f);
dataSet.setIconsOffset(new MPPointF(0, 40));
dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);
setSlicesColors(dataSet);
dataSet.setSelectionShift(0f);

// Outside values
dataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
dataSet.setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
dataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(20f);
dataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(0.2f);
dataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(0.4f);
dataSet.setUsingSliceColorAsValueLineColor(USING_SLICE_COLOR_AS_VALUE_LINE_COLOR);
binding.pieChart.setExtraOffsets(5, 10, 5, 5);

PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
data.setValueTextSize(11f);
data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLUE);

binding.pieChart.setData(data);

binding.pieChart.highlightValues(null);
binding.pieChart.invalidate();

binding.pieChart.setDrawMarkers(DRAW_MARKERS); // To remove markers when click
binding.pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(DRAW_ENTRY_LABELS); // To remove labels from piece of pie
binding.pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLACK);
binding.pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12f);

binding.pieChart.setUsePercentValues(USE_PERCENT_VALUES);
binding.pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(DESCRIPTION_ENABLED); // To remove description of pie

binding.pieChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.95f);

binding.pieChart.setCenterText(generateCenterSpannableText());

binding.pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(DRAW_HOLE_ENABLED);
binding.pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);

binding.pieChart.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.LTGRAY);
binding.pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(110);

binding.pieChart.setHoleRadius(58f);
binding.pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);

binding.pieChart.setDrawCenterText(DRAW_CENTER_TEXT);

binding.pieChart.setRotationAngle(0);
// enable rotation of the chart by touch
binding.pieChart.setRotationEnabled(ROTATION_ENABLED);
binding.pieChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(HIGHLIGHT_PER_TAP_ENABLED);

binding.pieChart.animateY(2000, Easing.EaseInOutQuad); // Starter Animation

legend = binding.pieChart.getLegend();
legend.setEnabled(GUIDE_ENABLED); // To show/not show Chart Guide
legend.setDrawInside(DRAW_INSIDE);
```

Is there any solution for implementing the chart I sent?

Answer (score 4):

try using `minAngleForSlices` param to set the minimum angle so that every sector can be seen and also maintain some distance between them.

Comment: Good Idea! Do you have any idea for setting background color for labels?

Comment: Is there a way to set min angle for the lowest value and the higher ones' slices be a little bigger?

Comment: ```PieDataSet#setValueTextColors()``` can be used to set colors for the text.

Comment: No I need to set background color for labels not text color

Comment: if the computed angle is less than the minimum value it'll be set to that minimum angle and the rest is calculated based on the remaining angle.
If the number of entries is more than to set minimum angle then the minimum angle will not be set.

Comment: Then you need to write a custom renderer to draw the rectangular box with text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234365/discussion-between-jagarapu-sahruday-and-alireza-noorali).

Answer (score 2):

I was faced same issue, to resolved overlapping label issue, add below line

`pieChart.setMinAngleForSlices(20f);`

Comment: Do you have any idea for setting background color for labels?